# WPF KeyBindings not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, key-bindings

Already gone through a dozen or more SO questions and articles on this topic. Nothing seems to work. Here's my simple system. A main `Window` that has a `Frame` to host `Page` objects in it. One of my `Page` object has the following stuff in it:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="PreviousRecordCommand" Text="Previous Record" />
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="NextRecordCommand" Text="Previous Record" />

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsAllOrders" Source="{Binding AllSalesOrders}" />
</Page.Resources>

<Page.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource PreviousRecordCommand}" Executed="PreviousRecordCommand_Executed" CanExecute="PreviousRecordCommandBinding_CanExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource NextRecordCommand}" Executed="NextRecordCommand_Executed" CanExecute="NextRecordCommandBinding_CanExecute" />
</Page.CommandBindings>

<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{StaticResource PreviousRecordCommand}" Gesture="CTRL+LEFT" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{StaticResource NextRecordCommand}" Gesture="CTRL+RIGHT" />
</Page.InputBindings>
```

And the code-behind has:

```
Private Sub PreviousRecordCommand_Executed(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
    Dim CurView = DirectCast(Me.Resources("cvsAllOrders"), CollectionViewSource).View
    CurView.MoveCurrentToPrevious()
    If CurView.IsCurrentBeforeFirst Then CurView.MoveCurrentToFirst()
End Sub

Private Sub NextRecordCommand_Executed(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
    Dim CurView = DirectCast(Me.Resources("cvsAllOrders"), CollectionViewSource).View
    CurView.MoveCurrentToNext()
    If CurView.IsCurrentAfterLast Then CurView.MoveCurrentToLast()
End Sub

Private Sub PreviousRecordCommandBinding_CanExecute(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)
    Dim MyView = DirectCast(Me.Resources("cvsAllOrders"), CollectionViewSource).View
    e.CanExecute = (MyView IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (DirectCast(Me.Resources("cvsAllOrders"), CollectionViewSource).View.CurrentPosition > 0)
End Sub

Private Sub NextRecordCommandBinding_CanExecute(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)
    Dim MyView = DirectCast(Me.Resources("cvsAllOrders"), CollectionViewSource).View
    e.CanExecute = (MyView IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (DirectCast(Me.Resources("cvsAllOrders"), CollectionViewSource).View.CurrentPosition < DirectCast(Me.Resources("cvsAllOrders"), CollectionViewSource).View.Cast(Of SalesOrderEntryModel.SalesOrder).Count() - 1)
End Sub
```

I can't get this to work. I have tried declaring the commands in my code-behind too. Doesn't make any difference. For reference, I have dozens of textboxes and other controls on my `Page` and need these keys to work wherever the current focus be.

Any help will greatly be appreciated.